# Converting a hex character within Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, hex

I'm currently programming in Assembly for an 8086.

The current task I'm doing is converting 4 hex digits into its decimal representation. I've tried following my tutors method but I'm confused at the section where I have to multiply the hex digit by a temporary value, especially as I've been told to make it 0 so every time the temp valued is multiplied it's always going to be 0 right?

The code I have so far is below, any help is really appreciated!

```
; ------------------------------------
; Name    : Gethex
; Function: converts a word (4 hex digits) into a numerical value
; Inputs  : Upto a word hex values input into the console
; Outputs : Return within DX the numerical conversion
; ------------------------------------

Gethex:
MOV BX,0H ;Temp value to 0
MOV CX,0H ;Counter set to 0
Gethexloop:
call Getch
push DX ; Putch requires DL, need to save current reg
MOV DL,AL
call Putch
pop DX ; restore DL reg
MOV BH,AH ;Use BH as temp storage as AH will be corrupted
cmp AL,30H ; ASCII 0
JL Gethexloop ; If less than 0 jump to the start as not an Alphabetical char
cmp AL,39H ; ASCII 9
JLE Nums ; If less or equal to 9 then it will be a number
cmp AL,46H
JLE Case ; Start the conversion procedure
Case:
SUB AL,10
jmp Convert
Nums:
SUB AL,30 ; Convert to normal number
Convert:
push AX ; Prepare to multiply
MOV AX,BX
mul BX
POP AX
ADD AX,BX
ADD DX,AX ; final value
ADD CX,1 ; Increase counter
cmp CX,3 ; if greater than 4 (0 being included so 3)
JG EndLoop
jmp Gethexloop
EndLoop:
ret ; return to calling statement
```

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few observations... First, a number is a number is a number. "hex" and "decimal" (and "binary" and "octal") are ways to represent a number - it's the same number. Converting a "hex representation" to a "decimal representation" in one step would be difficult (but possible... I guess). What you want to do is convert a hex representation to a number... and then probably convert the number to its decimal representation so we can print it.

Your "temp" variable, which I like to call "result so far" is set to zero to begin with, but it is not reset to zero for each character/digit! The general procedure is to set the "result so far" to zero, then for each valid digit encountered, multiply the "result so far" by the radix - ten for decimal, 16 for hex - then add in the new digit... converted from a character to a number, of course. Repeat until you run out of characters

`mul` is a perfectly fine instruction, but it has "hidden" operands (`ax` and `dx`, in our case). Multiplying by ten, we don't have too much choice, but multiplying by 16 can be accomplished by `shl reg, 4` with fewer "side effects". If you're really on an 8086, only `1` and `cl` are valid operands. An "immediate" other than one was only introduced in 80186 (80286 for practical purposes - 80186 was rare). You can almost certainly use it, but perhaps you're not "supposed to". I suspect you're "supposed to" use `mul` for this - makes it easier to check for overflow, in any case (if you wish to do that - limiting input to 4 characters should avoid overflow anyway).

I don't see the purpose of your `mov bh, ah` line - does  `ah` contain anything "interesting" at this point?

Almost any assembler will accept `cmp al, '0'` - same code as `cmp al, 48` or `cmp al, 30h`. I find that the former make the purpose of the instruction clearer, but it really doesn't matter.

`jl` and `jg` are for signed numbers - `0FFh` will be interpreted as -1, and will compare as "less than" zero. In this code, you won't encounter any numbers "big enough to be negative" so it won't matter, but `jb` and `ja` are for unsigned numbers (`0FFh` is interpreted as 255) and might be "more correct". That's just a nit-pick, but you might as well learn the difference - sometimes it does matter.

```
    cmp AL,46H
    JLE Case ; Start the conversion procedure
Case:
    SUB AL,10
```

Again, I like `cmp al, 'F'` better - but it produces the same code. If `al` is NOT less or equal (again `jbe` would be correct for unsigned), you fall through to `Case:` anyway. I doubt if that's what you want! And I don't see why you're subtracting 10. I would have thought 37h, or just 7 if you're going to subtract '0' anyway.

The pesky user is as likely to enter 'a'..'f' as 'A'..'F'. To do a proper "toupper", we would want to make sure the character HAS a "case". Here, we're going to be rejecting anything other than 'A'..'F' anyway, so it won't matter if we produce some junk by forcing characters that don't have an "uppercase". Make sure you've disposed of decimal digits first! `and al, 0DFh ; force to uppercase`. You may or may not want to do that - could just force the user to use the shift key. :)

User input ends with a carriage return - 13 or 0Dh - (as I recall...  Linux uses linefeed - 10 or 0Ah - but I think dos is 13). You might want to check for that first - before decimal or hex digits. I think your current setup will wait for 4 characters from the user, even if they've hit 'enter'. Probably not the expected behavior...

And yes, get a debugger and learn how to use it. Seeing what's happening step by step will help you a lot. I used to like David Lindauer's GRDB... (like DEBUG only brighter)...

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks for your help, I think I've got it working now and the debug results are correct :) thanks for your friendly tone :)

Comment: Do you have any recommendation for books or tutorials by the way?